# Update DATETIME values to <= GETDATE()-1

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking to update existing `DATETIME` values to yesterdays date and previous depending on their `DATE` order but keep the `TIME` part as it is.

For example assuming today's date is `2013-05-15 14:19:50`, and I have two existing `DATETIME` values of `2013-01-04 01:25:45` and `2013-01-03 01:08:33`. I would like to programatically update them to `2013-05-14 01:25:45` and `2013-05-13 01:08:33`.

Has anyone got a better way of doing this?

My attempt

```
IF EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1 
        FROM    tempdb..sysobjects 
        WHERE   id = object_id ('tempdb..#Date') 
        AND     xtype = 'U'
        )

        DROP TABLE #Date

CREATE
TABLE   #Date
        (
        ID          INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ID),
        [DateTime]  DATETIME
        )

INSERT
INTO    #Date
        (
        [DateTime]
        )

VALUES  ('2012-12-31 01:25:45')
        ,('2012-12-31 01:25:44')
        ,('2012-12-31 01:25:44')
        ,('2012-12-30 01:08:34')
        ,('2012-12-30 01:08:33')
        ,('2012-12-30 01:08:33')
        ,('2012-12-29 00:43:01')
        ,('2012-12-29 00:43:00')
        ,('2012-12-29 00:43:00')
        ,('2012-12-28 00:25:07')
        ,('2012-12-28 00:25:07')
        ,('2012-12-28 00:25:07')


SELECT  *
FROM    #Date   


;WITH   CTE
AS  (
    SELECT  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,[DateTime]) DESC) AS DENSERANK,
            [DateTime]
    FROM    #Date
    )

UPDATE  CTE
SET     [DateTime] = DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,[DateTime],GETDATE()-DENSERANK),[DateTime])       


SELECT  *
FROM    #Date
```

Comment: So the inputs are always the same values you've shown, and everything for `2013-01-04` should become yesterday, everything for `2013-01-03` should become the day before yesterday, etc?

Comment: The values are purely example dates. The actual table contains 5 years + worth of dates with the latest being 2012-12-31. So 2012-12-31 should become 2013-05-14, 2012-12-30 should become 2013-05-13 etc.

Comment: updated example inline values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this works in place of your current `UPDATE`. Whether it's better or not is debatable:

```
update #Date set DateTime =
     DATEADD(day,
        (select MIN(DATEDIFF(day,DateTime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) from #Date) --How many days since the most recent event recorded?
        -1, --Make that most recent event yesterday
     DateTime)
```

The simple observation to make is that the number of days to add onto each event is a constant - it's just the number of days from the most recent event until today.

Comment: logically yours makes more sense.

Comment: @Pixelated - once you've made the observation I mention, and if it turns out that the system is performing multiple scans, you can move the `select MIN(...)` out into a separate statement and store the number of days to offset into a variable, before performing the `UPDATE`